# Java-world apporach to localization - are there any implicits?

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, formatting, jvm

In .NET `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` properties are used implicitly in many cases.
For example calling `ToString()` on the `DateTime` value will format the date and time according to the culture settings of the current user.

On the contrary, Java's `LocalDate.toString()` has fixed formatting unless formatter is explicitly used.

Hence, there is a question:

Does Java avoid implicit dependencies on locale and have some fixed formattings unless otherwise explicitly specified by the developer? Should I worry about any implicits of that kind?

Comment: Java is wonderfully inconsistent on this. My advice would be to read the documentation for each instance you need, to be sure.

Comment: doesn't the doc say `The output will be in the ISO-8601 format uuuu-MM-dd`? Or I am missing something?

Comment: @Eugene The question is not about `LocalDate.toString` per se, rather about general approach to the subject.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, relying on what `toString()` returns is dangerous. There are quite a few notable exceptions (most importantly `StringBuilder`), but you should always be vary with calling `toString()` without checking the documentation first. (Having said that, how do those implicit dependencies work on a web server where each session can have different language configured for the UI?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `toString` is not for presentation

The `toString` method implementation on most classes is meant to be a textual representation of the object’s values for the purpose of debugging and logging, not for display in a user-interface. The `toString` method is defined in the root superclass of all classes in Java: [`Object::toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

The `toString` implementations in java.time use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These may or may not be appropriate to your users depending on the audience. Note that ISO 8601 formats are ideal when serializing date-time values to text for storing/exchanging data streams.

## java.time `format` method

For presentation to users, generally use methods other than `toString`.

The java.time framework has a convention of a `format` method to which you pass a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) object. That formatter can be made to automatically localize for you by calling the static factor `ofLocalized…` methods.

### `ZonedDateTime` example

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
// Better to specify time zone explicitly than rely on the default implicitly.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  
FormatStyle s = FormatStyle.LONG ; 
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
// Better to specify locale explicitly than rely on the default implicitly.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( s ).withLocale( l ) ; 
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> output: 28 août 2017 à 16:28:00 EDT
>
> zdt.toString(): 2017-08-28T16:28:00.107907-04:00[America/Montreal]

Note that `ZonedDateTime::toString` wisely extends the ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

### `LocalDate` example

As for your `LocalDate` question, we can extract the date-only value from `ZonedDateTime`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l  );
String output2 = ld.format( f2 );
```

> output2: lundi 28 août 2017
>
> ld.toString(): 2017-08-28

### Implicit defaults

As for implicit defaults, yes, the java.time classes use your JVM’s current default `Locale` implicitly if you do not specify. Ditto for time zone.

I suggest making a habit of **always specifying both explicitly** as seen in my code sample above. Both can be changed during runtime(!) by any code in any thread of any app running within that JVM. So relying on the default is, well, unreliable.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

FYI, the legacy date-time classes supplanted by java.time were poorly designed including some squirrelly choices for formatting. Do *not* look to those as guidance on proper design.